# StructureMap: How to register the same instance for all its interfaces

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

StructureMap newbie question.

```
public class SomeClass: IInterface1, IInterface2 {
}
```

I would like the following test to pass:

```
Assert.AreSameInstance(
    container.GetInstance<IInterface1>(), 
    container.GetInstance<IInterface2>());
```

How would I do an explicit registration of this?

I know in Castle Windsor I would do something like

```
kernel.Register(Component.For(typeof(IInterface1), typeof(IInterface2))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(SomeClass));
```

But I don't see any equivalent API

Comment: Wouldn't you just tell it to instantiate them as a Singleton?

Comment: Well...yes, but how to get the same singleton instance to implement each interface?  To be clear, only one SomeClass instance should ever be instantiated.

Comment: Oh, so you create a "base class" that implements both interfaces. Then you specify for that base class to return a singleton. Then for both interfaces, you specify that it return that base class. That should do it. Sorry, no dev environment here and I'm far from a guru who can whip up the syntax for you. :-/

Comment: Well yes, I understand the idea but the syntax is exactly what I cannot find. I tried 

x.For<IInterface1>().Singleton().User<SomeClass>();
x.For<IInterface2>().Singleton().User<SomeClass>();<br />

but that does not work

Comment: Correct syntax aside, I would expect something like this: `x.For<IInterface1>().Use<SomeClass>(); x.For<IInterface2>().Use<SomeClass>(); x.For<SomeClass>().Singleton().Use<SomeClass>();`. I know it seems a little redundant, but I believe that's how you'd do this.

Comment: Sorry Jax, that's not it - just tried and it doesn't work.  In any case, that would expose three services from the container when I would only to expose two.  Either way, that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, that's the best I can do to help you. Voting your thread up, hoping you can get better help from somebody else. Sorry!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => 
{ 
    x.For<IInterface1>().Singleton().Use<MyClass>(); 
    x.Forward<IInterface1, IInterface2>(); 
});
```

Comment: Tip: If this isn't working for you make sure you have the two type parameters to Forward() the right way around. I was caught out by assuming it was the "alternate" plugin type first.