# Interface Forwarding + Generics - StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have a generic base class that implements two interfaces.  Implementations do not take a type parameter.  It's registered with StructureMap like this:

```
asc.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(Index<>))
    .OnAddedPluginTypes(cpt => cpt.Singleton());
```

Currently I've kept the fields in consuming types declared as IAmOneOfTheInterfaces, but switched constructors to look for Index.  This is working OK but I would like to be able to pass the interfaces directly.

Is there anything similar to the interface forwarding feature mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535346/794) that will work with generics registered in this way?